# Missing android permissions when installing apk via adb

Tags: android

I developed an application that uses internet permissions. If i start the app from eclipse with "run as Android Application" everything works fine and the app gets started on the device (Nexus S).
If i stop the app and try to run it from the device i get the following logcat which points me to tha assumption that my app does not contain the correct permissions.

```
I/ActivityManager(  978): Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.dct.android.xbounds/.XboundsConfigurator bnds=[125,586][235,704] } from pid 1423
W/ActivityManager(  978): Permission Denial: starting Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.dct.android.xbounds/.XboundsConfigurator bnds=[125,586][235,704] } from ProcessRecord{40866718 1423:com.android.launcher/10057} (pid=1423, uid=10057) requires android.permission.INTERNET
```

in the manifest file i use:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

outside the application tag.

What i already tried is to export the app as signed apk and install it via adb, which behaves the same. The Nexus runs Cyanogenmod7.

Thanks for any help or ideas

Comment: I found the problem. It turned out that the manifest contained a wrong statement. android.permission.INTERNET was set inside the application tag too.

    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">

This was additional to the uses permission. This somehowe leads to the problem. Would be interesting if someone could explain what happened.

Comment: be sure to "answer own question" so this gets removed from the unanswered questions stack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set your Permission in your application-tag =)